# Replace strings in a string by a substring of those strings

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
s = '(X_xy09 and X_foobar or (X_abc123 and X_something))'
```

and I want to turn it into

```
'(xy09 and foobar or (abc123 and something))'
```

then - in this particular case - I could simply do

```
s.replace('X_', "")
```

which gives the desired output.

However, in my actual data there might be not only `X_` but also other prefixes, so the above `replace` statement does not work.

What I would need instead is a replacement of

a capital letter followed by an underscore and an arbitrary sequence of letters and numbers

by

everything after the first underscore.

So, to extract the desired elements I could use:

```
import re
print(re.findall('[A-Z]{1}_[a-zA-Z0-9]+', s))
```

which prints

```
['X_xy09', 'X_foobar', 'X_abc123', 'X_something']
```

how can I now replace those elements so that I obtain

```
'(xy09 and foobar or (abc123 and something))'
```

?

Comment: Tried using `re.sub`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Would love to, but don't know how to use it in this case. If you know how, feel free to post it as an answer... :)

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/Qs9ldO. What are the exact criteria for the pattern? Should it start with a word boundary or only after `(`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Ah, backreferencing! Great, that solves it. Please post it as an answer,  then I upvote and accept. The pattern is as simple as described: capital letter, underscore, some arbitrary stuff. There are not always `(` involved.

Comment: `re.sub(r'[A-Z]_(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])', '', s)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to remove an uppercase ASCII letter with an underscore after it, only when not preceded with a word char and when followed with an alphanumeric char, you may use

```
import re
s = '(X_xy09 and X_foobar or (X_abc123 and X_something))'
print(re.sub(r'\b[A-Z]_([a-zA-Z0-9])', r'\1', s))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Qs9ldO) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4YDuuS/1).

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `[A-Z]_` - an ASCII uppercase letter and `_`
- `([a-zA-Z0-9])` - Group 1 (later referenced to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): 1 alphanumeric char.

Comment: Note that it is equal to `re.sub(r'\b[A-Z]_(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])', '', s)`

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to replace a capital letter followed by an underscore, you can use the regular expression `r'[A-Z]_'`.

```
s = '(X_xy09 and X_foobar or (X_abc123 and X_something))'
re.sub(r'[A-Z]_', '', s)
```

You may need to add to it if you have other criteria not mentioned. (For example, some of your target values follow a word boundary and some follow parentheses.) The above might give you the wrong output if you have input like `XY_something`. It depends on what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Nice solution, too.

Answer (score 2):

Another `re.sub()` approach:

```
import re

s = '(X_xy09 and X_foobar or (X_abc123 and X_something))'
result = re.sub(r'[A-Z]_(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)', '', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
(xy09 and foobar or (abc123 and something))
```

---

- `[A-Z]_(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)` - `(?=...)` *positive lookahead assertion*, ensures that substituted `[A-Z]_` substring is followed by alphanumeric sequence `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Comment: Works fine. What is the `?=` part for?

Comment: @Cleb, that's positive lookahead assertion, see my explanation

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a lookahead assertion:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '(X_xy09 and X_foobar or (X_abc123 and X_something))'
>>> re.sub(r'\b[A-Z]_(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])', '', s)
'(xy09 and foobar or (abc123 and something))'
```

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> `(?=...)`
>       Matches if `...` matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a *lookahead assertion*. For example, `Isaac (?=Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s followed by `'Asimov'`.

Comment: Seems to be the same as RomanPerekhrest' answer but still deserves an upvote... :)